# Randomising Color Selection in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, colors

I'm using the construct theme on Wordpress. I would like to make it such that the `top_title` class changes color everytime the page is refreshed. I am not sure whether to edit the stylesheet or to place it in some unknown php file, I have tried a lot of suggestions from this site but none seem to work, in the stylesheet, this is what appears for the `top_title` class:

```
.top_title {background: #hexval}
```

Any suggesitons are welcome, but please be thorough, I am rather new at this particular section.

P.S. Also if possible I would like to choose the colors myself.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Your question is pretty broad. You should at least have an idea or a solution that did not work as expected. There are a lot of ways to solve this. A random color background can be realised using javascript or even php in your case. The Second question about the color selector also can be really simple or  complex, depending on your usecase. You will need to break your questions down to smaller ones and give us more information and the things you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/f4p7dj3g/ everytime you run you will get a new color

```
var colors = ['ababab','cc66ff','fefefe','ff0000','ff9900']; //colors array

//randomly pick color
var random_color = colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length))]; 

//add color as background color
$('.top_title').css('background-color','#'+random_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest picking your own colors.

Probably the easiest way to accomplish this is to create 1) an array of color codes, 2) choose your HTML element to target (in this case, `.top_title`), and 3) call a random position in that array.

So if you really want to use JS something like this in your header:
`<script> var colorArray = ["ffffff", "cccccc"]; </script>`

Then this in your HTML element:
`<div class='top_title' style="background:<script>colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];</script>">`

I think that is what you are looking to do?